# Css : customize word spacing property

Tags: css, styles, word-spacing

I have a line contain 3 words and I want to apply the CSS word-spacing property for just 2 word in this line, example :

this is the 3 words after word-spacing :

> 2018-mai-09 10:46 AM

I want it like this :

> 2018-mai-09 10:46AM

can any one give sol° !

```
  .photo-date
    text-align-last: center
    font-weight: bold
    font-size: 11px
    word-spacing: 10px
    color: #636e72
    margin-top: 5px
```

Comment: make them 2 words only?

Comment: I cant because it's a variable coming from backend server !

Comment: You can't **select individual text words** with CSS...only elements so this is not possible without changing the underlying HTML or use JS

Answer (score 0):

You could put the third word in a different component that doesn't load your .photo-date class. If the component that loads it is upside in the style hierarchy, you can make an auxiliar class to reset word-spacing to 0 px and applying it to this third word you want word-space reseted.